# How to make a batch command that list all the files in a directory?

Tags: command-line, batch

I am relatively new to batch coding, and am trying to make a file that will list all files in a specified directory, with the size, is a directory or not, etc. Currently, what I have is:

```
@echo off
echo Write directory name
set /p "directoryname=>"
forfiles /p %directoryname% /c "cmd /c echo @file @isdir @fsize @fdate @ftime"
pause >nul
```

However, this doesn't work, and I don't know why. What happens, is it asks for the directory, you type the directory (in my case, I use Documents), and instead of listing the files, it just asks again to type the directory, and keeps on repeating that.

How can I get it to work, so that you can type in the directory, and it will list the files and folders with their size, last modified times, etc?

Comment: Your file works as expected here.

Comment: I figured out how to do it now. What I need to do is run it as an Administrator(for some unknown-to-me reason) and put the directory in quotations.